# FTP sites open in Finder instead of in Safari

Tags: safari, firefox, login, ftp

I cannot log into FTP sites on my iMac (Intel Core i5, 2.8GHz, running OS X 10.6.7).

I probably created the problem when I installed Firefox and it took over as the default browser. I changed the default back to Safari, but then every time I try to log into the FTP at school (ftp://sws.pcc.edu), Firefox launched instead. I found a utility that said it would allow me to control internet protocol associations, which it kinda did. I tried to set Safari back to FTP but now FTP's open in Finder.

How do get things back to allowing me to login to FTP sites in Safari?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/328611/9058 for a way to accomplish this in High Sierra

Answer (score 2):

Safari does not support browsing FTP sites (displaying directory listings). Given a `ftp:` URL for a specific file, it will display or download it, but URLs for directories will be passed to the Finder instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this freeware app called [MisFox](http://mac.clauss-net.de/misfox/).  It will allow you to change the protocol helper for FTP.

Comment: Well, that helps in that it keeps it from feeding the FTP into Firefox, but now it is launching the FTP in Finder. Closer, but not quite the complete solution. Is there perhaps something I am missing here?

Thanks for the tip so far.

Comment: 0

My question is similar, but slightly different, and I hope someone can help. I don't want ftp links to open in Firefox, either. I want them to open in my FTP program (in this case, Transmit), and MisFox did precisely that! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`.

Open the file up in a text editor (any will do) - if you have Property List Editor installed, I'd still recommend a text editor, as it makes the next step easier.

Do a quick find in the document for "ftp" - once you've got the entry, it should look something like this:

```
<dict>
<key>LSHandlerRoleAll </key>
<string>com.panic.transmit </string>
<key>LSHandlerURLScheme </key>
<string>ftp </string>
</dict>
```

For me, Transmit is set to handle FTP. Change that line to `com.apple.safari`, save the file, and give it a shot. Make a backup first. Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on macOS Mojave. It looks like Safari doesn't want to handle FTP at all.