# How do I get Safari on OS X to stop ignoring the protocol part of a URL when the hostname starts with "ftp"?

Tags: macos, safari

I'm using Safari 8.0.5 on OS X 10.10.3. We have a server that's accessible over both FTP and HTTP. This server's name begins with "ftp." Whenever I try to connect to this server over HTTP, Safari dumps the connection attempt off to an FTP client, even if I use "http://ftp.example.com" (for the sake of an example) in the URL. This is super annoying. The only way I can get the correct behavior is to use a different web browser, such as Chrome or Firefox.

Can anyone suggest a way around this?

Thanks,
Sigsegv

Comment: So it ignores, even when you type: ´ftp://ftp.example.com´ ?

Comment: If I type that URL (ftp://ftp.example.com) into the location bar, it does try to connect to ftp.example.com over FTP.

Comment: On a question that FTP does not open with safari, I found this: Safari does not support browsing FTP sites (displaying directory listings). Given a ftp: URL for a specific file, it will display or download it, but URLs for directories will be passed to the Finder instead.     Might be old though...

Comment: Try right clicking safari, click Show Package Contents, go to Contents and move the .plist to your desktop, relaunch.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't without editing some plist files. Please refer to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12928/ftp-sites-open-in-finder-instead-of-in-safari) older question (not marked as dupe since the overall issue/question was different) for a few answers on this issue.