# How to set Firefox as default client for ftp:// links?

Tags: finder, high-sierra, firefox, ftp

How can I set Firefox as the default client for `ftp://` links? At the moment default client for `ftp://` is Finder, which I don't like.

I found a similar question, which is [7 years old](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12928/ftp-sites-open-in-finder-instead-of-in-safari) and the solutions don't work anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a free application called [RCDefault App](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) that allows you to set the default application for different protocols, file handlers, etc.

For example, for FTP, I can set whatever application I choose to handle that protocol...

[image]

Installation is extremly easy.  Once you download and open the DMG, simply copy the file to either `/Library/PreferencePanes` or `~/Library/PreferencePanes` (if you only want it accessible to your user profile)

After it's copied, open the application up from System Preferences and you can start customizing.

[image]

It hasn't been updated in a long time, but I just verified that it works on High Sierra.

Comment: We need a canonical for RCDefaultApp - fancy the challenge, ask & self-answer? [@Allan ... which SE strips, sometimes for the wrong reasons ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - I think I can type something up tonight....  :-)

Comment: Lovely ;-) ....

Comment: @Tetsujin - just added the answer

Comment: Nice one, comprehensive :)

Comment: The link is broken, the web site doesn't respond at all.